# Do I need Health Insurance to Qualify for a US Visitor's Visa?

Tags: visas, usa, health, insurance, b1-b2-visas

I will be going for a US visitor's visa (non-immigrant B1/B2) interview in Bern and have all the necessary documents but just remembered I do not have international travel insurance.

Is it required for me to have health insurance? Which kind of it is required?

Comment: No it isn't required.

Comment: It depends on the visa category. Some visa require you to have health insurance during your stay (but that will probably not be an "international health insurance"). Perhaps you can write which visa type you are applying for?

Comment: I applied for a Business/Tourist Visa (B1/B2).

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not necessary to have health insurance to receive a B1/B2 visa. It is not on [the list of documents required](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visitor.html#documentation). I can't find anything specific on the Bern embassy's website, but according to the London embassy, in their [non-immigrant visa FAQ](http://london.usembassy.gov/faq-niv-misc.html#niv072):

> Visitors and temporary residents are required to pay their own medical costs. As a result it is advisable to take out health insurance.

That is to say, you can be a visitor without health insurance. It may end up being expensive for you, however, if you are uninsured and do need medical treatment while there.

If you already expect to need medical treatment on your trip, and this fact comes up during the interview, perhaps your insurance (or lack of it) could be considered relevant to [evidence of](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visitor.html#documentation)

> Your ability to pay all costs of the trip.